# How can I get history data from my custom indicator value in MQL4?

Tags: mql4, indicator, mt4

I just make function that can get my custom indicator value in mql4. But, i want to get all the history data from my custom indicator value. I know it work with changing shift value. But, i want to get the data till 7-10 years before or more. How can i do that ? Thanks before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have 7 to 10 years worth of price data for the symbol you are looking at from your broker in your MetaTrader 4 terminal? If not, you will have to download/import it from somewhere.
There are various "paid for" sources available.

Comment: ohh sorry that's just my random calculation. what i want is just how to get all the history data that available in the mt4 terminal for my custom indicator. Any idea how to get that ? So basically, when i call my indicator function to get the value, its return all the values from the oldest bar till the newest

Comment: Either modify your indicator to write the values to a file, or if you don't have access to the source code, write another indicator using [iCustom](https://docs.mql4.com/indicators/icustom) to do the same thing